# timestamp filtering in the admin for an inlines

Tags: python, django, inlines

I am trying to manage the admin console.

I have two models, a venue and an event: events can happen at venues and events have a timestamp.

In my admin console I have added the events to be listed in the venues admin by using inlines.

However I want to set up a case where, ***by default*** only events from timestamp.now() into the future are listed and all events before teimstamp.now() are not shown.

I am limited to `Django 1.3` at the moment, but I believe `Django 1.4` has a type of solution in `SimpleListFilter`.

I have read somewhere that `DateFieldFilterSpec` can be used, but documentation and examples are very lacking. (Can you point me out some references if you have them?)

In the `python` code below there is no connection between the import of `DateFieldFilterSpec` to the code shown below, but I have no idea where or how they are connected.

***admin.py***

```
from django.contrib.admin.filterspecs import DateFieldFilterSpec

class eventInline(admin.TabularInline):

    list_filter = ('now')

    model = event
    extra = 1

class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [eventInline,]
```

When I use the above code I just get all the events, there doesn't seem to be any filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about modifying the queryset for that purpose (replace `eventdate` with the name of the field that holds the date of an event):

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib import admin

class eventInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(eventInline, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(eventdate__gte=datetime.now)
    model = event
    extra = 1

class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [eventInline,]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that is exactly what I was looking for, works as desired!

Comment: That's good news, because I didn't have the opportunity to test it myself.